# Can I place extended objects in a list in java along with the object it extended from?

Tags: java, list, object, extend

So I have two objects A & B, and B extends A.

Is it possible to have both objects in the same ArrayList?
Or what will I have to do to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use a `ArrayList<A>` and you can insert objects of B also. Here is an example:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
list.add(new B());
```

Comment: `List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();`

`list.add(new B());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you use Generics, you could define the list to be new ArrayList and both A and B can be stored in it.

The catch will be you won't know at the time you reference an index in the array whether the object you're getting is an "A" or a "B".